# If I wanted to use a batch file to restart 3 programs how would I do that?

Tags: windows, script, batch-file

I want to create a batch file that when ran it will exit 3 separate applications, wait a few seconds and then relaunch the same applications. Can someone assist me with some resources for accomplishing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
taskkill /im yourprogram.exe /f
taskkill /im yourotherprogram.exe /f
taskkill /im yourotherotherprogram.exe /f
timeout /t secondstotimeout
start yourprogram
start yourotherprogram
start yourotherotherprogram
```

Comment: When I start the programs again they need to be links to shortcuts on the desktop because they have startup parameters on them. How do I get them to start?

Comment: Just do `start yourprogramsshortcut.lnk`

Comment: Thanks @bali! I was able to use yourprogramsshortcut.lnk for one of them. The other I had to use start "" "c:\filepath\file.exe" and the other start "random title" "otherprogramshortcut.lnk" and it worked fine! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got it working! :)